# Can i add a way to check if my find() function contains a parameter and the return documents with only the specific field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i would like to know if there is a way to check within the list_all function if there is a parameter and only then to check and return the documents which have a field with the requested parameter.

This is my controller code:

```
exports.list_all = function(req, res) {
  Employees.find(function(err, list) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send(list);
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  });
};
```

This is my endpoint:

```
  app.route("/employeesByStore/:storeId")
    .get(Employees.list_all);
};
```

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

I finally applied the filter this way:

```
exports.list_all = function(req, res) {
  Employees.find({"storeId":req.params.storeId},function(err, list) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send(list);
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
exports.list_all = function(req, res) {
  if(Object.keys(req.params).length === 0) {
    // no params passed, do something
    return;
  }
  // a param is passed, let's query
  Employees.find(req.params, function(err, list) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send(list);
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  });
};
```

`req.params` will contains something like `{storeId: "1234"}`